# How do I define a class in Typescript that accepts an interface that has two fields for the same generic and guarantee they are the same type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I apologize for the confusing wording in the title, I'm having a hard time coming up with a one line summary for the question. Here is an example to explain what I'm trying to do:

```
interface Fish {
    type: 'fish';
}

interface Dog {
    type: 'dog';
}

type Animal = Fish | Dog;

interface MatingPair<T> {
    animal: T;
    otherAnimal: T;
}

class AnimalCollection<T> {
    private pairs: T[] = [];
    addPair<V extends T>(subject: V) {
        this.pairs.push(subject);
    }
}

let td = new AnimalCollection<MatingPair<Animal>>();

// Correctly generates error, dog is not a fish
td.addPair<MatingPair<Fish>>({
  animal: { type: 'dog' },
  otherAnimal: { type: 'fish' }
});

// Incorrectly lets dogs and fish be a mating pair
td.addPair({
  animal: { type: 'dog' },
  otherAnimal: { type: 'fish' }
});
```

I would like to be able to declare that `addPair` should receive a version of `MatingPair` that not just contains two "animals", but that the two animals are the same type.

Right now this code properly verifies that the call to `td.addPair` on the last line is receiving two animals of the same type (fish, in this case), but only because I'm explicitly setting `T` to be `Fish`. Is there a way to define this such that I can say both that `MatingPair.animal` & `MatingPair.otherAnimal` both have values that are types within the union Animal, but also that the type is the same for both of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reach your goal by restructuring the definition of the Animal collection class a bit like so:

```
interface Fish {
    type: 'fish';
}

interface Dog {
    type: 'dog';
}

type Animal = Fish | Dog;

interface MatingPair<T> {
    animal: T;
    otherAnimal: T;
}

class AnimalCollection<T>
{
    private pairs: MatingPair<T>[] = [];
    addPair<V extends T>(subject: MatingPair<V>)
    {
        this.pairs.push(subject);
    }
}

let td = new AnimalCollection<Animal>();

// Correctly generates error, dog is not a fish
td.addPair<Fish>({
  animal: { type: 'dog' },
  otherAnimal: { type: 'fish' }
});

// Correctly generates error, dog is not a fish
td.addPair({
  animal: { type: 'dog' },
  otherAnimal: { type: 'fish' }
});
```

Its not 100% what you ask for - but will solve the problem.

A little bit of explanation. Basically in your sample you are trying to do this:

```
let a: MatingPair<Animal> = {
  animal: { type: 'dog' },
  otherAnimal: { type: 'fish' }
}
```

And this is perfectly legal because both `animal` and `otherAnimal` are of type `Animal`, just different animals.

Whereas my subtle change makes code to look more like this:

```
let a: MatingPair<Dog> = {
  animal: { type: 'dog' },
  otherAnimal: { type: 'fish' }
}
```

And this is wrong as fish is not a dog.

In the real sample idea is the same, its just instead of `Dog` I have put there requirement that `V` is descendant of `Animal`. So either `Dog` or `Fish` but not both as they are incompatible.

Comment: Thanks Amid! This definitely does what I want. Do you know why the two act differently though? I'm having a little trouble understanding the difference.